# Monitoring beacons in Android oreo after app is killed

Tags: android, ibeacon, android-8.0-oreo, beacon, altbeacon

I'm making an app that executes some actions after a device detects a beacon while monitoring for beacons after app is killed.

I am currently using altbeacon for detecting beacons on android. It works fine on stock android phones but on a few devices like OnePlus i need to run a foreground service to detect beacons which results in a notification which indeed looks a bad user experience.

In a few devices like xiaomi, I need to enable a few permissions, which differs from manufacturer to manufacturer, thus making it nearly impossible to redirect users to those settings to enable those permissions.

Could anyone please provide a workaround?

Currently I am monitoring beacons during app kill and once detected I range beacons in order to get the uuid, major and minor since I need to differentiate between a huge number of beacons.

Comment: i guess foreground services only can do the required job. I had experince the same while developing BLE based app that should be able to detect singal even if the app is killed.

Comment: @Mr.Vicky it pops a notifications thats not desirable, any workaround for that? And also did you try on xiaomi devices? They need special permissions to be enabled, different settings for different phones how did you go around that?

Comment: yes Xiomi devices have issues with foreground services as it they have their own wrapper over Android OS.   I would recommend you to try solutions mentioned in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462286/android-foreground-service-gets-killed-on-mi-4-device-version-5-0-2

Comment: Thanks! @Mr.Vicky are there any more devices or manufacturers you encountered while you were developing so that i can take care of them?